# Image inside div that pushes content + content the same height of the image (with CSS Flexbox)

Tags: jquery, css, image, height, flexbox

I'm currently trying to make (not develop...) a template for a wordpress based website.

I've got an article page in which I have a `position: fixed` header/menu, a `position: fixed` image, some content that must appear after the image, and a dynamic footer.

In order to get a dynamic footer I used `flexbox` on the page.

What I intent to do is as following :

The image has NOT a fixed size. It fits to width's screen.

It can be possible the the `heights` is not equal to the screen's `height`.

If it's less than the screen's `height`, it's okay. But if it longer, then it would be nice if the div around the image got an `overflow: hidden` (until know it doesn't work, maybe because of flexbox).

The content appears right after the image (which is `position: fixed`) so the user can scroll down, and the content covers up the image.

But sometimes the content's `height` is smaller than the image's `height` so I need the content to be set as `min-heigh: window's height - footer's height`, which i've done with Javascript.

But it's not working well since the image's height is being pushed up by the content div (the image is much much taller). In fact, the bottom of the content acts like it fixed to the bottom, and the top of the div prevents the image from growing.

I maybe unclear (sorry, English is not my primary language), so feel free to ask questions.

I updated my template online so you can see the current version : [http://extatic.net](http://extatic.net/extatic/test-article/)

Comment: I created a JSFiddle to let you see/modify.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seeane/xcs2ksph/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with Paulie_D's answer using flexbox.

If you wanted to do it with JS, though, you would need to set the height in your code, like this: (CSS is for demo only)

```
$(function() {
  var h = $(window).innerHeight(),
    f = $('footer').innerHeight();

  $('main').height(h - f);
});
```

Full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/397d92g0/

Comment: Thank you vagrant,

It' nearly what I need!

The last thing to take into account it that I need the value to be set for min-height.

I tried to rewrite some of your code, but the minHeight parameter is not working (maybe bacause of flexbox?)

`var h = $(window).height();
  var f = $('footer').height();
  var r = (h - f);
  $('#postContent').css('min-height', r +'px');`

But now, the content is not fully pushed down by the image.
The end of the content div is at the bottom of the screen preventing the image to fully display.

I updated the website so you can see.

Comment: Seems to work for me: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/397d92g0/1/). Can you post a fiddle with your CSS so we can see what the conflict is?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my very first JSFiddle (youhou) : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seeane/xcs2ksph/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need javascript for that. Flexbox can do that natively.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  background: plum;
}
footer {
  height: 75px;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Hi Paulie and thanks for your reply.

I'm already using flexbox, and it's quite not what is the concern here.

I've got a `position: fixed` image and a content that scrolls over this image right after.

I want to set the height of the content of at least the height of the image so it would be full covered by the scrollable content.

You can see the problem here : [blog](http://extatic.net/extatic/test-article/)

Just scroll down : the white div with pink text must be at least the height of the background image (uncharted, here).

Comment: Then you need to clarify the requirement and the reasons/code for it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
var height = $("#footerID").height();// for height
var width = $("#footerId").width();// for width
var width = $("footer").width();
```

Comment: Hi Phoenix,

I'm just looking for the height. But as I mentionned it, i'm looking for a way to use the very html tag `<footer>`.

I found a few scripts that use `<div>`, and which work. But for `<footer>` I can't make things work and I don't know why.

Thanks.

Comment: Okay. My bad. I forgot the () after `.height`

--

`var f = $('footer').innerHeight();` is working!

Thanks for this answer!